# RBF interpolation MemoryError: Unable to allocate 97.8 GiB for an array with shape (13124997171,) and data type float64

Tags: python, interpolation

I have the following `df` of size (162019,3) for which I want to perform RBF interpolation.`x`,`y` columns are coordinates of different nodes and `vel` is velocity at that coordinates or nodes.
df:

```
x   y   vel
232883.607  364905.187  0.0
232915.233  364925.59   0.3913782463113478
232951.521  364949.617  0.571506505546009
232987.81   364973.643  0.616729970672177
233024.099  364997.67   0.5832793652211092
233060.387  365021.697  0.44159161279118175
233096.676  365045.723  0.30683455975038676
233132.964  365069.75   0.33623721151536723
233169.253  365093.777  0.3233954206611068
233205.541  365117.803  0.38487484068424677
........................
Many more lines...
```

The text file of the df is here [df.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZEEaA8odtlP6eATH8pQy0wf7qzbHI4GM/view?usp=sharing)

what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('df.txt', sep='\t')
rbfi = Rbf(a.x,a.y,a.vel)
```

Which gives following error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 97.8 GiB for an array with shape
> (13124997171,) and data type float64

I am using windows 10 and I have 64Gb of RAM in my pc. Please let me know how to fix it. I have tried changing virtual memory for managing paging file size but no luck. Please suggest if there is any alternative interpolation that can handle this much data and also do some smoothing. I have tried IDW which can do the work but the results are not smooth.

Comment: You will simply have to use a subset of your data for analysis.  The data set is too large.

Comment: Is there a way to set a boundary/distance around nodes to implement the RBF? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming a 32bit float point layout, you are talking about an array of minimum 50GB in memory (assuming contiguous, ignoring descriptors). I see you have a lot of RAM... but you will hardly be able to have that much available for this process

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I just saw your note that it is 64bits. So, too bad... double of that. You need to divide and conquer.

Comment: There are lots of other interpolation functions.  RBF has to create a 2D matrix of size N**2.

Comment: @ZVY545, There is one parameter `neighbors` in the [`RBFInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator), you can explore that.

Comment: Tim Roberts, Can you please suggest some that will be able to handle this large dataset? Rodrigo, I will look into `neighbors` option. I am afraid I can't use devide and conquer coz I will have to extract data along arcs inside the domain that goes one end to another end of the domain. So, I need the whole interpolation matrix together from where I will be able to extract velocity values for different arcs/lines.